# run terminal command in background when pressing html button

Tags: javascript, python, html, exec, child-process

Very beginner question.

I need to start a new flask application when clicking a HTML button.

In the header if have something like this:

```
<button ng-click="roviz.analysis();">Analysis</button>
```

When I click the Analysis button it should start a new flask application like the following:

```
this.analysis = function() { 

     execute a terminal command: " FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5004"
     after app.py has started
     it should immediatly open a new window with the flask webaddress
     window.open(localhost:5004);

                  };
```

Can someone tell me how to I connect to my local host and tell it to run the flask script once the button is clicked ?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question well. HTML will be running in a client browser and you want to invoke a python script where? in the client system?

Comment: You can't really run `python` in the browser....you can trigger it to run in a background task on the server, or you can compile it into JavaScript with something like [Brython](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython). It might help to narrow down the scope of your question and clarify it.

Comment: I updated the question. The clicked button should start a new flask application and open a window with the new local address of it. I read you can do this with AJAX, would appreciate an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute a python script from JavaScript (client side), you have to make a call to your server side, then you can call the python script.

Comment: The HTML will be only on my localhost. How to I call localhost to execute the python script ?

Comment: @DanielBaeriswyl the same way you would if it was hosted anywhere else - you have to have some server-side application (python, php, node.js, ruby, whatever) that execute's the python script, then from your client-side js send an HTTP request to this server-side application.

Comment: Could you give me an example how this could be done ?

Comment: When you are accessing some website, you are making a request to a remote server. So, when you're accessing a website on localhost, you should have a "server" that is in the same computer as your client part (that's the confusion you're making).
Giving a very silly example, is like you have two programs running at your computer, one is the browser (client part), and another is the server (where you could execute the python script, for example).